# Run animation after addLineToPoint for UIBezier path

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to force one animation waiting for the other, but without luck.

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
```

This is what I want to do:

```
[path addLineToPoint: point1];
```

and when this is done call this:

```
imageview1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5f, 1.5f);
```

Comment: Only this I can post is definition of path variable.   
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

Comment: any response? thanks a lot for some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I'm still unclear as to your needs, here is how you can call one animation ***AFTER*** the first one finishes:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                        delay:0.0f
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                   animations:^(void){
                     // Add in your first chunk of animated code.
                   }
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                                           delay:0.0f
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                                      animations:^(void){
                                        // Add in your second chunk of animated code.
                                      }
                                      completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                      }];
                   }];
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am not sure this is what I needed. I am not sure if bezierpath animation (addLineToPoint) have completion property